# Windows Php Fatal Error 'Soap Client' Extension is enabled, what am i doing wrong

Tags: php, soap-client

So I am trying to run a php page for fedex, while trying to run it I get the error

> Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found

So I went to the `php.ini` file on my windows server with iis and uncommented the line `;extension=soap_client.dll`, restarted IIS and I am still getting the same error.

I checked my PHP version and it is 5.2.4 so I am good there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I finally got the answer! After doing `phpinfo()` I found out that my load configuration file was (none) and configuration file was in the wrong place. After copying and pasting the php.ini file to my c:\windows file I was able to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I use the line:

`extension=php_soap.dll`

**NOT**

`extension=soap_client.dll`

I am using WAMP Server, PHP 5.2.5. So similar setup, I suspect its just the typo.

Also, Check your PHP Info to check whether its enabled or not.

Comment: Thanks @JustAnil and yes php info is enabled. Also it was just a typo meant to put php_soap.dll Thanks for the help though